# Retrieving Value from Anonymous Function & onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, ajax, onreadystatechange

I have a function from which I would like to return a value as a series of events whenever a button is clicked. However, I can't figure out how to retrieve the value from onreadystatechange. How can I make it so I can return `vicArray[vicID]`?

```
function selectVictim()
{
var vicString;
var vicArray;
var vicID;

var params = "url=queenofsheep.com/Sheep/victims.php";
var request = new ajaxRequest();

request.open("POST", "victims.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                             "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", params.length);
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

request.send(params);

request.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (this.status == 200)
        {
            if (this.responseText != null )
            {
                vicString = this.responseText;
                vicArray = JSON.parse(vicString);
                vicID = Math.floor(Math.random() * (vicArray.length - 1));
            }
            else alert("Ajax error: No data received");
        }
        else alert("Ajax Error: " + this.statusText);
    }
}
alert(vicArray[vicID]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Your `onreadystatechange` handler gets called long **after** the `selectVictim` function returns.

What you have here is, so to say, "asynchronous functions" - i.e. functions that generate their return value not immediately, but after a certain asynchronous process.

To deal with this, one has to use a callback to provide return value:

```
function selectVictim( callback )
{
    ...
    ...

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        ...
        vicArray[vicID] = ...;
        callback( vicArray[vicID] );
    }
}
```

Note the `callback` argument. Whoever calls this function, must provide another function for this argument. Then note how `selectVictim` calls the callback when the return value is ready.

Now wherever you call `selectVictim`, you must modify your code from:

```
function someFunc()
{
    doSomething();

    var vic = selectVictim();

    domeSomethingElseWithVictim( vic );
}
```

To:

```
function someFunc()
{
    doSomething();

    selectVictim( function( vic ) {

        domeSomethingElseWithVictim( vic );

    } );
}
```

Simple enough?

Comment: So what is another way to go about this?

Comment: Mmmm... Another way? I don't quite get the question. What another way?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a callback, in which you can pass the function that runs once the response is ready.

Add `callback` as a param:

```
function selectVictim(callback)
```

and then:

```
vicString = this.responseText;
vicArray = JSON.parse(vicString);
vicID = Math.floor(Math.random() * (vicArray.length - 1));
if (callback) {
 callback(vicID);
}
```

When you call the function you could do this:

```
selectVictim(function(vicID){ 
  console.log('This is the id: ', vicID); 
});
```

You can also pass the function as a value if you prefer not to do it directly. Note: it gets a little tricky if you make a ton of requests and you need to preserve the order in which they were made, but there are ways to handle that.